# Javascript cookies not working on anything

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I've been trying to get cookies to work using Javascript, but I have got nothing so far.

I've tried different browsers (Microsoft Edge, Internet Explorer, and Opera so far), CodePen.io, and a VSCode live server add-on (by Ritwick Dey). The live server add-on shows the cookie for some reason though.

The Javascript:

```
document.cookie = "name=value";
alert(document.cookie);
```

And the html (if you need it):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
  <body>

    <script>
      document.cookie = "name=value";
      alert(document.cookie);
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Really simple, but for some reason on every browser I've tried it shows nothing!
Reference Photo:
[Cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obgk3.png)

Also I'm really new to javascript so it's probably a very simple fix that I just can't see.
And my first time using Stack overflow.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the developer console?

Comment: Hello Welcome to SO. The error you're encountering is due to ***security restrictions*** applied to the document when it's being loaded from an environment that sandboxes the content. This can happen in embedded environments like iframes or online editors like CodePen.

Comment: There is no problem with your code.

Comment: Nope, the only thing it says is that it navigated to the file on my pc.

Comment: How can I turn the security restrictions off? Edit: WAIT I got it! I have a raspberry pi Nginx server that has a webserver on it and I moved the html file to it and it worked! Thank you!

Comment: Does anyone mind posting a answer so I can mark this question done?

Comment: If you want you can add the answer to your own question as well. Provide all possible details to it so that others in future also find this helpful. Cheers